# visual studio 2013 on rebuild ddl Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a asp.net solution which consists of multiple class library whose dll' are been used in one web application.When I build and rebuild the class library I don't face any issue, later when I try to build and rebuild the solution few of my dll files gets deleted from bin.Tried adding reference path but in vein.

Warning :   Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "classlibrary2". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.    classlibrary1

Error   10  The type or namespace name 'Classlibrary1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Note:All projects are in same framework

Comment: Is your solution has both projects and does the web application has reference to ClassLibary1?

Comment: yes have added references to my web application of classlibrary1